# Why does annotate affect the density number in each bin?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The issue here is that when I use annotate with ggplot, for some reason, my numbers which are placed in each bin, change. I am not sure why but I need to find out. I have not posted the data, because the only way that you would see this issue is if you had the entire data set, which his too large.

In the After graph, I circled a few numbers that changed.

BEFORE CODE:

```
ggplot(gb, aes(x = Y*100, y = Y1*100, fill = typeoft)) + 
  geom_bin2d(bins = 10, aes(alpha = ..count..)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","red")) + 
  geom_text_repel(bins = 10,stat = "bin2d",
                  aes(label = round(100*..density..,1)),
                  size = 2,direction = "y") +
  facet_wrap(~type, nrow = 1) +
  geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(.05,1)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
```

AFTER CODE:

```
ggplot(gb, aes(x = Y*100, y = Y1*100, fill = typeoft)) + 
  geom_bin2d(bins = 10, aes(alpha = ..count..)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","red")) + 
  geom_text(bins = 10,stat = "bin2d",
            aes(label = round(100*..density..,1)),
            size = 2,check_overlap = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(~type, nrow = 1) +
  geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(.05,1)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  annotate(geom = "text",label = c(.1,0,.3),x = -.87,y=-.75,size = 2) +
  annotate(geom = "text",label = c(.2,.1,1),x = -.29,y=-.18,size = 2)
```

Comment: I took a look at your link, & didn't find the variable names used in the code. Are you sure it's the right file?

Comment: I have changed the names in the question. thanks for letting me know. Any thoughts? @Z.Lin

Comment: It seems `annotate` changed the range of x-axis. While the number of bins is the same, the boundary of bins changed.

Comment: is there a way to solve that issue? and not have the range change?

Comment: I do not have any solution for this. In addition, I also could not reproduce the plot you show.

Comment: I am sorry I edited the code again. I realized that I had forgot to include *100, so each value for Y and Y1 should be multiplied by 100. Check the code now. @mt1022

Answer (score 1):

To make the binning reproducible you need to set the axis ranges explicitly to be the same for each plot (see the `scale_*_continuous` elements below). To make the labeling with `geom_text_repel` reproducible, you need to set the same seed (for producing the random shifts in the label positions) when generating each plot. This can be done with the `seed` argument in `geom_text_repel`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(grid.arrange)

# Read data
gb = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nwlezien/49ac446d3f924b2ab70e10b442883ade/raw/0769320b71c507884bfeb28a0639f3cfbacf31f1/data.csv"
gb = read_csv(dat)

# Function to generate plot components
pfnc = function(bins, title) {
  list(geom_bin2d(bins = bins, aes(alpha = ..count..)),
       scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","red")), 
       geom_text(bins = bins, stat = "bin2d", seed=2,
                       aes(label = round(100*..density..,1)),
                       size = 2, direction = "y"),
       facet_wrap(~type, nrow = 1),
       geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0),
       scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(.5,1)),
       theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")), 
       theme(legend.position = "none"),
       labs(title=title),
       scale_x_continuous(limits=range(gb$Y*100) + c(-0.15,0.15)*diff(range(gb$Y*100)), expand=c(0,0)),
       scale_y_continuous(limits=range(gb$Y1*100) + c(-0.15,0.15)*diff(range(gb$Y1*100)), expand=c(0,0))
       )
}

p1 = ggplot(gb, aes(x = Y*100, y = Y1*100, fill = typeoft)) + 
  pfnc(10, "original plot")

p2 = ggplot(gb, aes(x = Y*100, y = Y1*100, fill = typeoft)) + 
  pfnc(10, "with annotations") +
  annotate(geom = "text",label = c(.1,0,.3),x = -.87,y=-.75,size = 4, colour="lightblue") +
  annotate(geom = "text",label = c(.2,.1,1),x = -.29,y=-.18,size = 4, colour="lightblue")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=1)
```

[image]

These plots would be much easier to interpret with labels in the center of each bin, which you can get if you change `geom_text_repel` to `geom_text`:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry I edited the code again. I realized that I had forgot to include *100, so each value for Y and Y1 should be multiplied by 100. Check the code now.